# Validation not working after leaving list grid field in smartgwt

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm trying to get changes made to a cell in a ListGrid to validate against other cells in the ListGrid. The Item being added needs to have a unique name from the items in the item container, as well as any other items being added. I have the ListGridField.validateOnChange set to true. My validator looks like this:

```
CustomValidator validator = new CustomValidator() {
    @Override
    protected boolean condition(Object value)
    {
        String name = (String)value;

        if (_eeNames.contains(name))
        {
            setErrorMessage("Item Container already contains an Item with the name \" 
                + name +"\".");
            return false;
        }

        RecordList records = listGrid.getDataAsRecordList();
        int numFound = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < records.getLength(); i++)
        {
            if (records.get(i).getAttribute("addAs") == null) continue;
            if (records.get(i).getAttribute("addAs").equalsIgnoreCase(name)) 
            {
                numFound++;
            }
            if (numFound > 1)
            {
                setErrorMessage("Another Item being imported has the name \""
                    + name + "\".");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

This ends up working fine on its own for checking against Items already in the container. However, I noticed it didn't validate correctly for names entered in for other items. What I found to be happening, or not happening, was the record's value was not getting updated from the edit, and so wasn't getting checked correctly. Changing `if(numFound >1)` to `if(numfound >=1)` only led to a chenged item name finding itself invalid on later validations. I tried adding a changed handler to change the record value when changed, which almost worked. After leaving the cell, the validation just stopped working. No further changes would validate. I debugged, and confirmed that after leaving the editing cell, the validation was never called again.

I've also had the inexplicable problem of the validation sometimes saying a name is valid even though its already in the item container.

Any idea on what's causing this? And any solutions to this problem? Thanks in advance.

[edit 6/3/11]

The validations incorrectly return false have been solved, thanks Charles. However, I'm still having problems. While editing, the validation works perfectly, but when I exit the editor for the cell, the error message and icon is cleared, and an invalid value is shown as valid. I've tried adding an exitHandler to the field and having the listgrid validate the row number of the event when it's fired, but doesn't seem to do anything. This also happens seemingly sporadically, sometimes working sometimes not. If a name is entered initially and it's invalid, entering and then exiting the editor causes it to remove the invliad flag. Unfortunetly that's about the only behavior that's consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListGrid is managing two pieces of data: the original record loaded from the server, and the changes to that record which have not been saved.  The latter are called "editValues".  To access a copy of the Record with editValues applied (as though they had already been saved) call getEditedRecord(rowNum).  More background in the ListGrid Editing overview:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Editing.html

Comment: That worked for getting rid of the incorrect false validations. However it looks liek my real problem is elsewhere. After moving from the edit, failed validations are being set to true, or no validation is taking place at all. I'll add that to the original question as well.

Comment: You should find that your validator is being called on cell exit if there were changes to the cell.  Add logging or a breakpoint to see exactly what you're returning - the validator may simply be returning no error when you intended an error.  If this doesn't help, you need to post the full code so someone can actually run it and see what's going wrong.

Comment: Looking through the rest of my code, it turns out there was a piece of code that was manually setting the field for the records, this was screwing up the validation initially. Removing the code fixed it and the validation works fine. Thanks for your help.